# React component calling another react component with a lambda function?

Tags: reactjs

I see react component being returned like this:

```
function callingComponent():
   return (<weirdComponent pop={'test'}>
            {(var1, var2, var3)=> 
            <anotherComponent/>)}
           </weirdComponent>
          );
```

What is the meaning of (var1,var2,var3)=> Isn't it a lambda function ?

Comment: Well, yes `(var1, var2, var3) =>  <anotherComponent/>` this is a lambda function. What is the real question? :)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko, but is this lambda function being passed to anotherComponent ? Are var1,var2,var3 props of anotherComponent. Does anotherComponent take a function as a prop? What role does this lambda function play here ?

Comment: No, the function is passed to `weirdComponent` as `children`. The pattern is called ["render props"](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening is that `weirdComponent` is taking the lambda provided as a [render prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html), which it uses to render `anotherComponent`. This likely happens by `weirdComponent` accessing [`this.props.children`](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#children-in-jsx) (or `props.children` for stateless). In this case, as the lambda is passed as a child to `weirdComponent`, `children` will refer to it. Then, `weirdComponent` will call the lambda function, something like `this.props.children(a, b, c)`, passing 3 (or less) values as `var1`, `var2`, and `var3` to the function in order to render `anotherComponent`.

I'm assuming that this is a simplified example and that the lambda somehow uses the values of `var1`, `var2`, and `var3`, otherwise they serve no purpose here and instead `anotherComponent` could just be rendered directly